# Animating edge color change on selection in vis.js

Tags: javascript, api, vis.js, vis.js-network

I'm wondering if it is possible to write a function that handles the selection colors of edges in vis.js.

Currently, selecting an edge changes the color of the edge from `color` to `highlightColor`, defined in the node module.

Is it possible with the API to define a fade function that eases between `color` and `highlightColor`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Also add what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

well, it is possible, although there's no direct API and you have to do some work about it:

- add `selectEdge` and `deselectEdge` [events](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#Events) handlers
- learn how to change `color` and `highlightColor` inside these handlers so that they are applied at once (may be it will work without additional steps, may be it will require re-rendering)
- in the `selectEdge` handler, change `highlightColor` to that of unselected edge and then animate it (change several times gradually to that of selected edge)
- in the `deselectEdge` handler, change `color` to that of selected edge and then animate it (to unselected edge)
- profit